# How to use ajax/js to select options in a list form field?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have list fields on an event registration page, some with multiple selections. For instance, here is one:

```
<select id="expertise" class="select-large required" name="expertise[]"  multiple="" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-invalid="true">
<option value="Disaster Management">Disaster Management </option>
<option value="Energy Security">Energy Security </option>
<optgroup label="Environment">
    <option value="Climate">Climate </option>
    <option value="Resource Security">Resource Security </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

The form is quite large and when someone registers I send them a unique ID that they can use to auto load their previous data. For the most part it works fine. Here is the code I have on the reg form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function inputFocus(i){
if(i.value==i.defaultValue){ i.value=""; i.style.color="#000"; }
}
function inputBlur(i){
if(i.value==""){ i.value=i.defaultValue; i.style.color="#888"; }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".previousreg-link").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();                // Prevents browser following #hash 
        $(this).hide();                        // hide the button
        $(".previousreg-form-container").show();   // Show the form parent
    });

    $('#previousregbox').click(function(){
        this.checked?$('.previousreg-form-container').show(100):$('.previousreg-form-container').hide(100);
    });

    $(".previousreg-form-container form").on("submit", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();              // Don't send headers
        /* Clear result div*/
        $("#result").html('');
        //alert( $(this).serialize() +"\nWILL BE SENT TO PHP" );
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "/components/com_icagenda/previousreg.php",
            data    : $(this).serialize(),      // `this` is our form
            success: function(xml){
                //alert("success");
                //alert($("email",xml).text());
                if  ($("message",xml).text() == "") {
                    $("#result").html('Your previous registration data has been loaded.');
                    //$("#email_slug").val($("email",xml).text());


                    //var $xml = $.parseXML(xml);
                    var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));
                    //$("#response", xml).children().each(function(e) {
                    //$(xml).find('response').children().each(function() {
                    $xml.find('response').each(function() {
                         var data={}
                         $(this).children().each(function() {
                             //alert($(this).text());
                             //data[this.tagName]=$(this).text();
                             $("#"+this.tagName).val($(this).text());
                         })
                    });

                } else {
                    $("#result").html($("message",xml).text());
                }
            },
            error:function(xml){
                //alert("failure");
                $("#result").html('There was an error on the server. We apologize for the inconvenience.');
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The above works for text fields, radio controls, and single select lists. Honestly, I am not even sure how I got it working for lists, because the js calls do not mark the list option as selected. But I suppose setting the val is enough. Problem is this is not working for multiple select lists, as I suspected would happen.

Can someone show me how I would edit my code to factor in multiple select lists? In the XML response, multiple select list value will be a string with each value comma separated.

I am just not familiar enough with jquery syntax to figure out how to make the edit, and with the optgroups, not sure how I would loop through all the options, which I suppose would require some sort of recursion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
function setOptions(input) 
{
    var options = input.split(",");
    $("#expertise option").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(options.indexOf(value) >= 0)
            $(this).prop("selected", true);
        else
            $(this).prop("selected", false);
    });
}
var data = "option1,option2,option3";
setOptions(data);
```

Comment: That worked! I would up vote, but it won't let me. For it to work I had to prevent this line in my code from executing: $("#"+this.tagName).val($(this).text());